# VirtualBox/Net-Framework: Software [WISO Mein Geld 365] runs slow, unresponsive and has renderung issues

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, .net-framework

I am running Windows7 (guest) on VirtualBox on my Linux (openSUSE Tumbleweed) pc (host). I use this mainly for an accounting and homebanking software software (Wiso Mein Geld 365), which i cannot directly run on linux (native or by using Wine).

Lately i had to upgrade the software to the newest iteration which heavily uses Microsoft .NET (the old version did not needed the Net-Framework). The software runs... but very poor, which means the functionality is there (no crashes) but it is not very responsive and sometimes some parts do not render properly (minimizing and maximizing again can help), the context menu is not working/opening most of the times.

Is there anything i can do about this?

Comment: You will need to determine the reason for the performance drop.  Have you tried increasing the amount of memory the virtual machine has access to?  Does the application now support hardware acceleration?

Comment: The VM is configured with 8GB RAM, 6 CPU-Cores, 256 MB graphic memory (VBoxVGA), the guest addions installed experimental 3d support. Windows 7 itself and other applications installed on it run fast and reliable... i do not know if the application supports hardware acceleration... i think the problem is Net-Framework related... I am also wondering if creating a Windows 10 VM will help maybe